# Understanding battery capacity measurement circuit

Tags: diodes, relay, schematics

I came across this battery capacity circuit on the internet and it seems interesting and useful. So I would like to build it myself. However, I don't fully understand the working of some of its parts so would like to learn how those work.

Forgive me if some of my questions seem too obvious to you but they aren't for me :)

[image: Circuit Schematic]

1. How is the switch S2 controlling the relay? and is it directly connected to the relay with the dotted lines?
2. The relay shown is a dual pole one, so I assume that the switch S3 will be connected to one of the pole, while the switch S2 will be connected to the other pole. Is that correct?
3. What is the purpose of the 3.3V diode next to the 12V source? Is it there to regulate voltage in some way? Also the symbol itself is confusing, as on the internet I could find the same symbol for a Zener as well as for the Schottky diode. Which one is it in this case?
4. The reference point is shown twice in the circuit, so does it provide a kind of verification to check if the circuit is properly connected or is it actually the voltage point that feeds the main circuit?
5. I suppose the "COM" is common ground and all the other grounds are connected to this point. Right?
6. I have never seen the electromechanical clock thingy. Is it a thing of past or still used these days? Would be very helpful if you can give a real example as searching on google shows me pictures of huge clocks :)
7. lastly, how would the circuit stop discharging the battery upon reaching the cutoff voltage? I assume the 2n7000 will only disconnect the electromechanical clock. So I wonder how will the discharge circuit be stopped at the end of test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. How is the switch S2 controlling the relay? and is it directly connected to the relay with the dotted lines?

S2 is the relay contact.  When current flows through the coil, S2 closes.  S1 initially connects the battery to activate the relay, then S2 holds it on.

> 2. The relay shown is a dual pole one, so I assume that the switch S3 will be connected to one of the pole, while the switch S2 will be
>    connected to the other pole. Is that correct?

Correct.

> 3. What is the purpose of the 3.3V diode next to the 12V source? Is it there to regulate voltage in some way? Also the symbol itself is
>    confusing, as on the internet I could find the same symbol for a Zener
>    as well as for the Schottky diode. Which one is it in this case?

It's a Zener diode which will conduct if the reverse voltage is over 3.3V.  In conjunction with the series resistor, that gives you a regulated 3.3V reference.

> 4. The reference point is shown twice in the circuit, so does it provide a kind of verification to check if the circuit is properly
>    connected or is it actually the voltage point that feeds the main
>    circuit?

Those symbols indicate that there is a connection between those points not indicated by a line.  They're usually used for nodes with a lot of connections, or with connections on another sheet.  They can also be used to force meaningful net labels instead of autogenerated ones.

> 5. I suppose the "COM" is common ground and all the other grounds are connected to this point. Right?

Right.  It's drawn here to indicate a "common" or ground terminal (or off-sheet connection) for the 12V supply.

> 6. I have never seen the electromechanical clock thingy. Is it a thing of past or still used these days? Would be very helpful if you can
>    give a real example as searching on google shows me pictures of huge
>    clocks :)

It's intended to indicate the discharge time of the battery.  You might be able to use a battery-operated analog watch initialized to 12:00.  I think they specify an electromechanical clock so that it retains the last reading, but there's other timers that would work.

> 7. lastly, how would the circuit stop discharging the battery upon reaching the cutoff voltage? I assume the 2n7000 will only disconnect
>    the electromechanical clock. So I wonder how will the discharge
>    circuit be stopped at the end of test?

The battery level is measured at the + input of IC1B, and compared to the level set by P2 on the negative input.  As long as the battery voltage is higher than the set point, the output of IC1B is high, and Q2 keeps the relay energized.  When the battery voltage goes below that point, the output of IC1B goes low, Q2 turns off, and the relay turns off.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation. It makes sense now :)

Comment: I suppose the circuit with the 3.3v ref voltage, would only be able to measure < 3.3V batteries or more specifically AA batteries. However, I would like to test 3.7V and 9V li-ion batteries. So by replacing the 3.3V zener to a 4.3V or 9.1V zener, this setup should work. Or do I need to make other modifications as well?

Comment: What if I use a variable voltage supply and remove the zener ref voltage, wouldn't that be much simpler for testing different voltage batteries and should still work?

Comment: I will be using an MCU to measure the voltage and output it to the display. So if I just poll S3's state as high or low, it should be possible to program a timer that starts and stops depending upon the state of the S3 and remove the clock altogether.

Comment: @Zaffresky you can either change the reference, or change the parts that select cut-off voltage, to measure higher battery voltages. Or both. The biggest problem is that the LM358 needs to have the reference and battery voltage below 10V when powered with 12V, so it may be better to divide down the battery voltage than to change the reference, especially if you have a stable reference already. It depends what is the largest battery voltage you have. A 3.7V cell would have about 4.2V when full.

Comment: @Justme The largest battery I want to test is a 9V one. I don't quite understand what do you mean by  _"The biggest problem is that the LM358 needs to have the reference and battery voltage below 10V when powered with 12V "_. Why would it be a problem?

Comment: Also by _divide down the battery voltage_ you mean using a voltage divider before the test battery or something else?

Comment: The LM358 works to spec only when the input voltages are within a certain range.  The top end of the range for this part is 2V below the supply.  I agree with @Justme that it would probably be easier and better to use a voltage divider to extend the voltage range--for instance, replace that 100K bleeder resistor with a 10K and 27K in series, with the 27K going to the battery line, the 10K going to ground, and the junction between them connected to the + input of U1B.  That gives you a threshold range of about 0-12.2V.  (Luckily, the 358 input range is V- [in this case, ground] on the low end.)

Answer (score 2):

1. It's the relay that controls the switch S2, not the other way around. It's one half of the contacts of the DPST relay.
2. Yes, S3 is the other half of the DPST relay contacts.
3. It's a 3.3V Zener diode to generate regulated 3.3V reference voltage. A Schottky would make no sense in there.
4. Those are labels for the same connections so you know they are connected even without drawing a wire between them. Reference is generated in one place, and it is used in another place.
5. Yes, the COM wire of the 12V supply is selected to be the 0V common ground for this circuit.
6. That's a standard wall clock that runs with 1.5V battery. Are you sure you've never seen one? The relay can disconnect the battery to stop the clock, which will show you how long it took to discharge the battery.
7. When battery is discharged, the relay opens both the wall clock battery contacts to stop it, and at the same time, it also opens the battery contacts to disconnect it.

Comment: 7. IC1B measures the battery voltage and compares it to the voltage on P2.  When the battery voltage falls below P2, then Q2 is turned off, which turns off the relay, which opens the S2 and S3 contacts.

Comment: @Justme I've definitely seen the regular wall clocks. I confused it some kind of mechanical counter thing. But thanks for pointing out :)